# How to integrate mailchimp in a grommet.io form?

Tags: reactjs, mailchimp, grommet

Looking to create an email signup form on a landing page. I'm using a react component library called Grommet (grommet.github.io). What does my onClick function need to be in order to capture the email using mailchimp?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial website. What have you tried so far?